# How to return requested results?

Tags: sql, t-sql

For each region show the region and number of countries with populations of at least 10 million.

The table is called bbc and has the following fields:

- name   (refers to the names of the countries)
- region  (refers to region of the world)
- area     (area in miles)
- population  (how many peoples said country has)
- gdp      (gross domestic product)

I was thinking I could do something like:

```
 SELECT region, COUNT(name) FROM bbc 
 GROUP BY region 
 HAVING population > 10000000
```

Comment: or `WHERE population > 1e7`, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show *all* regions, and within each region to count the number with populations greater than 10 million, then probably this is easiest:

```
SELECT region, SUM(CASE WHEN population > 10000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BigCountries
FROM bbc
GROUP BY region
```

So if you have a region where no countries have a population greater than 10000000, you'll still have a row with that region name and a 0.

---

From your comments to @Yograj Gupta question - if you want regions where *all* countries have populations > 10000000, then you can either modify the above:

```
SELECT region, COUNT(*) as Cnt,SUM(CASE WHEN population > 10000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BigCountries
FROM bbc
GROUP BY region
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN population > 10000000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Or just exploit a simpler property:

```
SELECT region, COUNT(*) as Cnt,MIN(population) as LowestPop
FROM bbc
GROUP BY region
HAVING MIN(population) > 10000000
```

where the minimum population for any country in the region is > 10000000, then all countries must have a population > 10000000

Comment: Everything about your answers make sense.  Yet the solution is not working.  Maybe you could take a look sqlzoo.net/SUM_and_COUNT

It is question number 7.  :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use either

```
-- For getting count of country name which has population > 10000000
SELECT region, COUNT(name) FROM bbc
WHERE population > 10000000
GROUP BY region
```

or

```
-- For getting region which has SUM(population) > 10000000
SELECT region, COUNT(name) FROM bbc 
GROUP BY region 
HAVING SUM(population) > 10000000
```

Comment: I believe the question I was asked was looking for all regions where all the countries within that region have a population greater than 10000000

Comment: To further clarify... I'm not looking for regions where the sum population of countries is greater than 10 million, but rather regions where every individual country has a population greater than 10 million.

Comment: For some reason, their answer gives middle east a count of 10... your query returns 9... not sure why there is a difference.